Igx-grid allowFiltering="true" (Change sorting of column filter drowdown list), filter date list according to recent date first
Igx-grid allowFiltering option, I want to display filter date list according to current date on top.
here is link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ivs7wc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgrid%2Fgrid-excel-style-filtering-sample-3%2Fgrid-excel-style-filtering-sample-3.component.html
enter image description here
I am try this. - this.grid.sort({ fieldName: 'OrderDate', dir: SortingDirection.Desc, ignoreCase: true });
it's display like -
Mar 11, 2001
Mar 12, 2001
Jan 12, 2002
Feb 17, 2002
Mar 17, 2002
Mar 28, 2002
I want to display like -
Mar 28, 2002
Mar 17, 2002
Feb 17, 2002
Jan 12, 2002
Mar 12, 2001
Mar 11, 2001

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What you are trying (calling this.grid.sort()) is actually applying sorting to the data view, rather than the Excel-style Filtering UI. Don't see a direct option to change the directing to descending, so to modify that UI you want if to either target it via templates (bit too involved for this case) or better yet one of strategies exposed that feed the UI. Will drop an answer with suggestion.

There are multiple strategies to override that drive the filtering, including a complete override the unique values, but you case seems to simply need to change the directing of the filter date values to descending.
For that purpose, the Grid's IFilteringStrategy has getFilterItems method that's explicitly responsible for providing the unique values that go into the Excel style filter list.
In that case taking the base result with already unique values and a simple Array.sort should do:
class MyFilteringStrategy extends FilteringStrategy {
    public override async getFilterItems(column: ColumnType, tree: IFilteringExpressionsTree): Promise<IgxFilterItem[]> {
        const result = await super.getFilterItems(column, tree);

        if (column.field === 'OrderDate') {
            result.sort((a, b) => {
                if (!a.value) return -1;
                if (!b.value) return 1;
                return (b.value as Date).getTime() - (a.value as Date).getTime();
            });
        }

        return result;
    }
}

Note this assumes the default handling where values are already unique and doesn't try to handle equals.
This section of the Excel Style Filtering topic shows how to supply a different strategy to the grid. Basically:
public filterStrategy = new FormattedValuesFilteringStrategy();

<igx-grid
  [allowFiltering]="true"
  filterMode="excelStyleFilter"
  [filterStrategy]="filterStrategy">

And you get descending dates list this way:

